# '->' and '.' used on a reference to an object?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a code base and I came across something that kinda stumped me, or at least made me think twice for a bit.

I have a parameter to a function passed by reference like so:

```
const PathTile &refTile
```

at one point in the function a member function of the `pathTile` is accessed like one would expect, with the `->` operator, just a few lines down the same member function is accessed using the `.` operator. The weird thing is the code works. Is this `->` implicit when the `.` is used??

I ask because I'm not sure if the previous guy did this intentionally or not. Should I change it?

Comment: You can overload `operator->`.

Comment: It's bad to assume the previous programmer did things unintentionally.

Comment: do you have separate `pathTile` and `refTile` variables? `refTile` members should be accessed with `.`.

Comment: Also, members of a reference should be accessed with `.`.  I would _not_ expect to see `->` with a `const PathTile &`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have to do with the fact that you can:

```
foo *x=new foo();
foo &y=*x;
```

Now:

```
x->bar();
```

and:

```
y.bar();
```

Are equivalent, legal, valid, will compile, and do the same thing etc.

More code please

Comment: Did you mean `foo& y = *x;` perhaps?

Comment: This is it. I'll stick with the '.' for convention.

Answer (score 4):

> at one point in the function a member function of the pathTile is accessed like one would expect, with the -> operator

This is incorrect. Members of references should generally be accessed via `.`. As Seth pointed out in the comments, `->` can be overloaded... and this is useful when you want to pretend your type is a pointer. `.` cannot be overloaded.

> Is this -> implicit when the . is used??

No, there must be another explanation. (different variable and overloaded `->` come to mind immediately)

Answer (score 2):

There are special objects called smart pointers that can be used almost the same way as regular pointers. To provide that they overload operator -> but they are real objects so you can call their own methods through . so:

```
struct Foobar { void method(); };
smart_pointer<Foobar> spointer;
spointer->method(); // called method() of class Foobar of instance where spointer points to
spointer.reset();   // called reset() of object spointer itself.
```

There is no difference if you use reference, so if spointer in example above would be a refernce to type smart_pointer it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, the accesses are not the same/interchangable simply because they are references.

One common case is when the referenced object is a container object (i.e. smart pointer); `obj.member` may access the container member while `obj->member` may be specified to access the contained object's member via notational convenience of `operator->()`.

I'd check `PathTile` for `operator->()`.

Comment: There is no overloaded -> operator.